# Is it possible to detect DTMF tones using C#

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, dtmf

I am trying to detect caller id information from telephone line. The caller-id information received is in DTMF tones (not FSK). How can I detect this DTMF tones ? Is Phone and Fax Modem capable of it ? The Phone and Fax Modem is capable of detecting FSK information, but not DTMF information.

Notes: I am using C# language and .NET as developing platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, modems are capable of picking up DTMF.  This Code Project article should have some clues on how to do it with TAPI:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/IVR.aspx

For a more modern c#-ish project, look here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/devangpro.aspx

Comment: Thanks for inputs.. I will try to implement it and get back to you in case of difficulties.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using a TAPI library and detecting DTMF is pretty basic stuff and most of them support it. Check out [this library](http://atapi.codeplex.com/)