# Detect DTMF Tones C#

Tags: c#, dtmf

I have wav file in which using the naudio lib i have been able to get raw data out of the wav files.

Does any one know how to loop though the data in chuncks detecting DTMF tones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone with http://www.tapiex.com/ToneDecoder.Net.htm

Its cheeap and does a good job at detection. All the others i found dont seem to do the job or have no documentation

Comment: Spent 2 days trying various methods to do the same thing, and this component has everything I need. It will even run in a windows service. There's another component called WaveEx.Net that will read from a sound card. Well worth the money!

Answer (score 3):

The NuGet package [DtmfDetection.NAudio](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DtmfDetection.NAudio/) provides extension methods and wrappers to detect DTMF tones in live (captured) audio and pre-recorded audio files.

On the [GitHub site of the project](https://github.com/bert2/DtmfDetection) you can find a [sample program](https://github.com/bert2/DtmfDetection/blob/master/example/dtmf-detector/Program.cs).

Answer (score 1):

Well, on the top of the google is this:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dtmf-cs/

But, if you want to use heavy artillery, you can always FFT your samples and check what two freqs are seen the most.

BTW, do some searching before you post anything, and you'll come up with:

[Detect a specific frequency/tone from raw wave-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808893/detect-a-specific-frequency-tone-from-raw-wave-data)

or even

[Is it possible to detect DTMF tones using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951396/is-it-possible-to-detect-dtmf-tones-using-c)

Comment: yeah ive tried that dont seem to be able meanfully docs with it

Comment: I’ve search before and studied all those articles none of them give a simple explanation or useful code examples. code exmaples would be nice

Comment: You can have code examples for something like THAT.  IMHO, every such library should come with some example, and if it doesn't, leave the message to the project admin, ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

DTMF stands for dual-tone multi frequence signaling. So you have to detect the two frequencies used to send a signal.

You have to transform your timebased audio material into the frequency domain typically by using a FFT algorithm.

Here i found a very old VB5 program with source online which does exactly what you want i think: http://www.qsl.net/kb5ryo/dtmf.htm

EDIT: Ok, maybe its better to take a look at the suggested [C# lib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dtmf-cs/).